# Python Count up & Down loop

Tags: python, loops, counter, countdown

How can I simply transform this loop to count up from 1 to 100, and display the numbers? I'm starting to code recently. It works fine when counting down, but I can't figure out how to make it go from 1 -100

## example:

```
count = 100
while count > 0 :
    print(count)
    count = count - 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start at 1, and change your conditional to break out when you reach 100. Add 1 each loop through.

```
count = 1
while count <= 100:
    print(count)
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 15):

If you use a for loop it gets really easy:

```
for number in range(1,101):
    print(number)
```

And for going from 100 down to 1:

```
for number in range(100,0,-1):
    print(number)
```

Answer (score 4):

Can try 'reversed':

```
>>> for i in reversed(range(1,11)):
...   print i
... 
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: Or you can just change the numbers inside the range()                                                                   >>> for i in range(11,1,-1)

Answer (score 1):

just start your count at 1, change your check statement to check if the number is less than 100, and use "count = count + 1" Should work, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Basically just do the opposite of what you've already got.

```
count = 1
while count < 101:
    print(count)
    count = count + 1
```