# I need help in python2 to making a counter that can count up and store the count data into a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, count, counter

This is my code, I have to add a counter into my code so that every time the button is pressed it will count up once and i would like to to keep on counting up every time the button is pressed. I searched online and found out that I have to store the counter data to a file but i do not know how to write a code to do the count and store the count to a file. please help

```
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
import sys
import webbrowser

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

button=40
button1=11

car=("/home/pi/Desktop/htb.mp4")
car2=("/home/pi/Desktop/htb2.mp4")

GPIO.setup(button,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(button1,GPIO.IN)
quit_video=True
player=False

while(1):
    if GPIO.input(button)==0 and GPIO.input(button1)==1:
        print " thru beam  "
        os.system('pkill omxplayer')
        os.system('omxplayer -r htb.mp4')
        sleep(.5)
    if GPIO.input(button1)==0 and GPIO.input(button)==1:
        print " that other sensor "
        os.system('pkill omxplayer')
        os.system('omxplayer -r htb2.mp4')
        sleep(.5)
    else:
        print " home "
        webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com.sg/')
        sleep(.5)
```

Comment: I have tried add the code from here " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401542/python-count-up-down-loop " and also here " http://www.hackingwithphp.com/8/9/0/a-working-example-making-a-counter " but it did not work. I am not very sure as I have no experience in programming and this is my first time.

Answer (score 0):

Such a program will help you:

```
import os

if not os.path.isfile("counter.txt"):
    counter = 1
    f = open("counter.txt","w+")
    f.write(str(counter))
    f.close()
    print (counter)
else:
    f = open("counter.txt","r+")
    counter = int(f.readline())
    counter += 1
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(str(counter))
    f.close()
    print (counter)
```

As you see below, it shares a counter between different runs:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
1
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
2
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
3
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
4
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
5
>>>
```

Comment: Hi I have tried your code and it counts during the "else", I would like to do count during the "if". So that when I trigger a button at "if" then it will counts up by just 1, until the next trigger. Thanks for the help

Comment: @lnuy Put whole the above `if...else...` in the button body!